# What is the equivalent in python to this code line in perl $conf{svnlook} log --revision $rev $repo

Tags: python, perl, formatting, format, string-formatting

What is the equivalent in python to this code line in perl

```
$conf{svnlook} log --revision $rev $repo
```

i'm looking in python for something as neat as that...

Comment: its a line i used in a perl script...

Comment: Was it in some backticks or `system()` call? It looks like you are calling an external program, whose name is stored in the `$conf{svnlook}` hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be exact, what you have there is not a perl command, that is a formatted string... I am assuming you are sending a string command to the shell... to do so in python you can do this...

```
# assign conf as a dict()
# assign rev and repo as variables
import os
os.system('%s log --revision %s %s' % (conf['svnlook'], rev, repo))
```

**EDIT**
To answer your question about string formatting, there are [python template strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) and [python format strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatexamples)... I will demonstrate format strings in the python shell...

```
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(latitude='37.24N', longitude='-115.81W')
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
>>>
```

However, this is still more verbose than `perl`

Comment: I must say in perl it looks nicer because they can incorporate $rev $repo inside the string itself I wish i had that in python!!! nothing like that?

Comment: its still too much heavy i just wanted simple reference to varialbe in strings... :/ with the {} i still need to do later .format etc

Comment: @Jason, I understand... I was addicted to `perl` for 10 years before switching to `python`... although I must confess that overall, I am glad I switched...

Answer (score 4):

That's not really valid Perl.   Are you sure it wasn't something like this?

```
my $log = `$conf{svnlook} log --revision $rev $repo`;
```

That's calling the [svnlook](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.ref.svnlook.html) program, an external program not part of Perl.  You can do [the same thing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

```
from subprocess import call
call([conf['svnlook'], 'log', '--revision', rev, repo])
```